# Multiple 3D Object Transformations

Tags: graphics, 3d, matrix-multiplication

I'm working a basic modeling application. I read that you can implement it by having a list of objects with identifiers (such as 1 for cube and 2 for a sphere) and then apply each object's instance transformation (a combination of the translation, rotation, and scaling). Since these transformations are not commutative, order matters. In general, you would define an overall transformation matrix as M=TRS where T=translation, R=rotation, and S=scaling.

My question is that if I perform a series of transformations, would it be the same as the total transformations of each type? As in, something like this:

M = t1*r1*t2*s1*r2*s2 =? t1*t2*r1*r2*s1*s2 = TRS

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not the same. Matrix multiplication is not commutative so you cannot change the order of the multiplications for the different transformations.